# ASP.NET Web Api the underlying provider failed to open mdf already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my solution structure:

**Application**

This is an ASP.NET MVC application. It has this connection string in `web.config`:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
   Initial Catalog=aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c;
   Integrated Security=SSPI;
   AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c.mdf
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

It references `ApplicationClassLibrary`.

**ApplicationApi**

This is a Web API application, with this connection string in `app.config`:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
     Initial Catalog=aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c;
     Integrated Security=SSPI;
     AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c.mdf" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

It references ApplicationClassLibrary

**ApplicationClassLibrary**

This project contains `dbContext` and `IdentityModel`, and migrations are run from here.

The issue is that when I run my ApplicationApi and call this code using Postman:

```
public String CheckUser(string username, string password)
{
     var user = dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username);
     return user.UserName;
}
```

I get this error:

> Database 'C:\Users\uuu\source\repos\Application\Application\App_Data\aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
>
> Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\uuu\source\repos\Application\ApplicationApi\bin\Debug\aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c.mdf' as database 'aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c'

So basically for some reason, my `ApplicationApi` is trying to create or use an existing `.mdf` file? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: But i'll need that connection string to access the database?

Comment: I meant remove initial catalog code let the remaining be there.

Comment: {"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\\Users\\uuu\\source\\repos\\Application\\ApplicationApi\\bin\\Debug\\aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}
Oh now I get this when I removed the InitalCatalog code from my ApplicationApi

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. It came from this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6dfdcc22-7a81-4e8f-a947-c1ce6982d4b3/flustered-a-database-with-the-same-name-exists-or-specified-file-cannot-be-opened-or-it-is?forum=sqlexpress

What its saying is because I already have a parent connection string that created the db file, I should reference it only. So instead, my connection string for any other project that relies on the same database should be simple like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=aspnet-Application-5cb5b1db-6c48-49c7-93b2-ba81ded39c1c;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```